# angular.js how to alter variable value step by step

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my html code

```
<div ng-app='app'>
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="myVar=7">
    {{myVar}}
    <span ng-init="myVar=myVar+5">{{myVar}},</span>
    <span ng-init="myVar=myVar+15">{{myVar}},</span>
    <span ng-init="myVar=myVar+37">{{myVar}},</span>
</div>
```

and script

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('MyController', function() {});
```

The output I'm getting is 64,64,64,64

but I want output as 7,12,27,64

I'm trying to find things like ng-repeat but I cant kept these in an array

Comment: I have little understanding and I know angular.js doesn't work how I'm thinking, but there should be other ways to achieve this. I need those ways..

Comment: WHy can you not do {{myVar+5}}, inside the span instead of using ng-init.

Comment: Dear Chandermani, I want to update the variable then and their itself.

Answer (score 1):

In every `ng-init` you're altering the value of `myVar` that is data bound to all other instances; and that's why they all show the same. So rather do:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="myVar=7">
    {{myVar}}
    <span>{{myVar+5}},</span>
    <span>{{myVar+15}},</span>
    <span>{{myVar+37}},</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh my god.. yes.. I tried this in the begining itself, but not worked. 

Now it is working.. thanks alot

Comment: is there any way to re-assign the myVar variable
like..
{{myVar}} {{myVar+=5}} {{myVar+=7}}

Comment: Just to be clear, it's important to know the workflow of AngularJS (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) and realize that EVERY `ng-init` will run prior to any interpolation.